# WCF transport security &&messags security mode question

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

suppose there are three machine: client,load balancer and Service machine ,and the Service  is invoked by the load balancer.

If we want to secure the communication between client and Service via Load balancer.
Some kind of person tellme use the two following mode:

transport security mode:(SSL,HTTPS)
making two SSL connections - between client and load balancer, and between load balancer and service.and the  load balancer must decrypt and understand it before dispating to service ,
so it is unsecured because the load balancer  can "see" the content of the messages.

messages security mode:
message is passed to load balancer, and the load balancer kept the message encrypted and just forward to the Service,so it is secured because the load balancer  can not  "see" the content of the messages.

So,my puzzle is if we use transport security mode,

why can't we establish one SSL connection between client and service  directly instead of created  two SSL connections , so the role of the  load balancer is just forward the encrypted  the messages to  service just as it's role in the message security model?

if that is the true,we can ensure the security between client and Service by using SSL,because the load balancer  can not  "see" the content of the   encrypted  messages.

is it true?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

Check out this link: http://loadbalancer.org/load_balancing_methods.php
(not trying to advertise, just a quick google find for 'load balancing methods')